# Gradle: JavaExec in a single process

Tags: java, process, gradle

With gradle's [JavaExec](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/JavaExec.html) task, I can execute a main method, in a child process, and pass string arguments to it. Is there an equivalent task that allows running an arbitrary Java (or Groovy) method within the gradle process, and therefore allows passing object arguments?

Ultimately, what I would like to do is configure object properties (not just strings) using an approach similar to [this](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/11/gradle-goodness-using-properties-for.html), and pass those properties to any method on the runtime classpath (`classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath`).

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this atm is to add your dependencies directly as buildscript classpath dependencies and call the methods directly in your task.

Comment: Is it possible to add the compiled src to the buildscript classpath? It seems like a chicken-and-egg problem. Adding `classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath` to the buildscript block results in: `No such property: sourceSets for class: org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.DefaultScriptHandler` which makes sense. Buildscript dependencies must be static, whereas JavaExec can depend on the output of previous tasks?